# How can I determine the exit status of an sfdx command in a shell script?

Tags: salesforcedx, github-actions

I am running my **sfdx** deploy command in a shell script as part of a Github action. Currently, the script is reporting success even if the sfdx command fails. This means the build is succeeding even when it fails.

How can I query the result of the sfdx command (`force:source:deploy` with tests run) and fail the script and have a failed build reported when the deploy command fails?

Here are the lines of code in my shell script:

```
sfdx force:source:deploy -x $DEPLOY_FOLDER/package/package.xml --verbose -c -l RunSpecifiedTests -r $testsToRun
echo -e "Deployment to [$targetEnv] successful."
```

And here is the end of the output from the script as seen in Github:

```
ERROR running force:source:deploy:  Deploy failed.
----> Deployment to [localBuild] successful.
```

Thanks in advance,
Peter

Comment: Have you tried testing the [exit code](https://www.shellscript.sh/exitcodes.html) returned by the sfdx command or using conditional command [chaining](https://www.thegeekdiary.com/6-bash-shell-command-line-chaining-operators-in-linux/)? This is more a question around shell scripting than Salesforce, so probably should be posted elsewhere...

Answer (score 3):

Thanks Phil W for your comment. I am inexperienced in Shell scripting and was unaware of the generic exit code. I posted here thinking I needed to know how to determine specific error details of the sfdx command.

I used the following code to now correctly determine the result of the sfdx command.

```
sfdx force:source:deploy -x $DEPLOY_FOLDER/package/package.xml --verbose -c -l RunSpecifiedTests -r $testsToRun
if [ "$?" -ne "0" ]; then
    echo -e "$RED_TEXT----> Deployment to [$targetEnv] FAILED."
    exit 1
fi
echo -e "$GREEN_TEXT----> Deployment to [$targetEnv] successful."
```